# Facebook Javascript SDK getLoginStatus Returning Unknown (completely inconsistently)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, facebook

I'm authenticating the user successfully using PHP, getting the access token, etc. For part of my app however I'm using Javascript to load images/friends and such. In the past I had no problem with getLoginStatus, but now it's returning

```
status: unknown
```

about 80% of the time. It seems to be working a bit better in Firefox then in other browsers, but I've still gotten it to happen there, so I think that's just a fluke. The only thing that I can think of that may have affected this is trying to log out the previous user before someone tries to log in using php (however I've tried to revert the file and test without it and still doesn't work, so unless it's somehow messing up my persistent data I have no clue):

```
$fb_key = 'fbsr_'.$facebookConfig['app_id'];
setcookie($fb_key, '', time()-3600);
$facebook->destroySession();
```

Can't seem to find anything on google about this, so I really have no clue what's up. At this point maybe I need to just use the access token I have through php to make queries through the javascript api (since I can still get this successfully). I'm going to look into that right now but in the mean time I thought I'd post in case anyone has any ideas!

Here's my JS code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : pre_fbAppID, // App ID
        channelUrl : pre_absURL + '/channel.html', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    doFacebookLogin();

    //Facebook can notify us when the user logs in and logs out
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        // do something with response
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        // do something with response
    });

    function doFacebookLogin(){

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            checkLoginResponse(response);
        }, true);
    }
```

...

Comment: This had everything to do with the php authentication I was using, I'm not sure what part of it exactly, but when I switched to only using JS authentication and not php authentication at all (I still retrieved data via php, but just didn't login using it) it completely fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

`the user is not logged into Facebook at this time and so we don't know if they've authenticated your application or not (unknown)`

I think you are not initializing your JS SDK correctly or call it before FB.init.
(same as: [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4509971/fb-getloginstatus-called-before-calling-fb-init))

Can you post your javascript block regarding the FB.getLoginStatus ?

UPDATE:
Why do you have "true" in the FB.getLoginStatus ?

> To improve the performace of your application, not every call to check the status of the user will result in request to Facebook's servers. Where possible, the response is cached. The first time in the current browser session that FB.getLoginStatus is called, or the JD SDK is init'd with status: true, the response object will be cached by the SDK. **Subsequent calls to FB.getLoginStatus will return data from this cached response.**

If the first call returns Unknown -> all others will return the same.
Can you try without the "true"?

UPDATE #2:

> To receive the response of this call, you must subscribe to the **auth.statusChange** event. The response object passed by this event is identical to that which would be returned by calling FB.getLoginStatus explicitly.

You subscribed to all others except `auth.statusChange`

Comment: I tried taking off true and adding auth.statusChange and neither worked. Even the js api example provided by facebook isn't working for me (the user can log in successfully but the data isn't persistent, the next time they try to log in they get unknown status and have to press login again). I just create a work around using php but it's not quite ideal.

Comment: Are you seeing any Javascript Errors ? In which browser are you testing this ?

Comment: No JS errors. Tested in IE8, IE9, Chrome, Safari, and FF. I'd say it happens at least 50% of the time in all browsers besides FF, for some reason I've only seen it happen a couple of times in Firefox (I don't know if this is just coincidence or related to something).

Answer (score 0):

Initialization:

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v2.2'
            });
            //FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            //    statusChangeCallback(response);
            //});
        };
```

Start facebook login:

```js
function startFace() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        }
```

Call status:

```js
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                loginFacebook();
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                //some code
            } else if (response.status === 'unknown') {
                FB.login(function (response) {
                    statusChangeCallback(response);
                });
            } else {
                //some code
            }
            
        }
```